# Magento 1.9: Fatal error: Class 'FANCourier_Ship_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, helper

Need some help with an error.
I've installed a third party module, it is a shipping module. After I've installed it and I go the shipping methods in the backend, I get this:

> Fatal error: Class 'FANCourier_Ship_Helper_Data' not found in
>   app/Mage.php on line 547

My `config.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <FANCourier_Ship>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </FANCourier_Ship>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <ship>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>FANCourier_Ship</module>
                <frontName>ship</frontName>
            </args>
        </ship>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <ship>
                <file>ship.xml</file>
            </ship>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <ship>
            <class>FANCourier_Ship_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>ship_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </ship>
        <ship_mysql4>
            <class>FANCourier_Ship_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <ship>
                    <table>ship</table>
                </ship>
            </entities>
        </ship_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <ship_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>FANCourier_Ship</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </ship_setup>
        <ship_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </ship_write>
        <ship_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </ship_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <ship>
            <class>FANCourier_Ship_Block</class>
        </ship>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <ship>
            <class>FANCourier_Ship_Helper</class>
        </ship>
    </helpers>
</global>
<default>
         <carriers>
            <FANCourier>
                <showmethod>1</showmethod>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>ship/carrier_FANCourier</model>
            </FANCourier>
     </carriers>
   </default>
```

And I also have a `Data.php` file in the module's `Helper` folder that looks like this:

```
class FANCourier_Ship_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Comment: clear cache and check again.

Comment: also check http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-helper-data-not-found-error/

Answer (score 1):

So... after some research and trying different things, the solutions was **recompiling**.

In the backend go to System > Tools > Compilation and then hit Run Compilation process.

I think that after the config.xml and data.php solutions, it's the main cause and it will work on 93.4% causes of helper not found problems.